# I don't know why my function Flip() in JavaScript isn't returning anything. I want it to return if it is heads or tails

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, random

JavaScript - I don't see anything obvious that is wrong

```
function Flip() {
    var Probability = Math.floor(Math.random());
    if (Probability > 0.5) {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML("Heads!");
    }
    if (Probability < 0.5) {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML("Tails!");
    }
```

HTML - Nothing should be wrong in the HTML (besides selectors)

```
<body>
    <button onClick="Flip()" id="submit">FLIP THE COIN</button>
    <p id="message"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: probably `return true` missing..!

Comment: Where is the tax() function as mentioned in your question title?

Comment: Shouldn't it still send a message via paragraph

Comment: I changed it to Flip()

Comment: Reload the page, I accidentally typed Tax() then i edited it to Flip()

Comment: innerHTML isn't a method, it's a property: you'd have to assign to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign innerHTML as below, it is not a function.
Check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/r1sd1mrm/).

```
function Flip() {
    var Probability = Math.floor(Math.random());
    if (Probability > 0.5) {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Heads!";
    }
    if (Probability < 0.5) {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Tails!";
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! For all the help!